# Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $f(x)f(yf(x))=f(x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+$$$f(x)f(yf(x))=f(x+y)$$

A start: set y=0 to get $f(x)f(0)=f(x)$. So $f(0)=1$ unless $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: If $f$ is identically equal to $1$, $f$ is a solution.

Comment: $0$ is not in the domain, not in the image either, so your thought gives nothing. Are you looking at general all kinds of functions or you have restrictions like being continuous?

Comment: Right; somehow I was thinking of nonnegative reals.

Comment: As a first step I would consider $g(x)=\log f(x)$.

Comment: I can prove that if we make the additional assumptions that $f$ has $1$ in its image and is continuous, then $f$ is constant $1$.  I'll write this up as answer if I can't come up with anything better shortly.

Comment: Cool. I'd like to see your solution with these additional assumptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To find all functions $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x)f(yf(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660662/to-find-all-functions-f-0-infty-rightarrow-0-infty-such-that-fxy)

Answer (score 3):

Actually we don't need to use the condition that the function is continuous.

Denote the condition $f(x)f(yf(x))=f(x+y)$ by $(1)$

Case I: for some $t$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$, $f(t)>1$.

We put $(x,y)=(t,t/(f(t)-1))$ in $(1)$, and consequently we have $yf(x)=x+y$. Thus we have $f(x)f(yf(x))=f(x+y)$ with $yf(x)=x+y$ and thus $f(yf(x))=f(x+y)>0$. Then $f(t)=f(x)=1$, a contradiction.

Case II: for all $t$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$, $1≥f(t)>0$. Moreover, there is at least one $t$ such that $f(t)=1$.

Then we prove that $f$ is constant. Otherwise, there is another positive real number $r$ such that $f(r)<1$.

We put $(x,y)=(t,kt)$ where $k=1,2,\dotsc$.
We have that $f(t)f(ktf(t))=f((k+1)t)$, that is, $f(kt)=f((k+1)t)$. Then $f(kt)=f((k-1)t)=\dotsb=f(t)=1$ for any postive integer $k$.

There is an integer $n$ larger than $r/t$, which means $nt>r$. We put $(x,y)=(r,nt-r)$, and we have $f(r)f((nt-r)f(r))=f(nt)=1$. Thus $f((nt-r)f(r))=1/f(r)>1$, a contradiction.

Case III: for all $t$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$, $1>f(t)>0$.

Then we prove that $f$ is injective firstly. Otherwise, we will have that $f(u)=f(v)$ with $u>v>0$. Let $(x,y)=(v,u-v)$ in $(1)$, we have $f(v)>f(v)f((u-v)f(v))=f(u)$ (because $1>f((u-v)f(v))>0$), a contradiction.

Then, let $x=1$ in $(1)$, we have that (denote $f(1)$ by $c$) $cf(cy)=f(y+1)$. Let $y=1/f(x)$ in $(1)$, we have that $cf(x)=f(x+1/f(x))$. Consider the two equation above, let $y=x/c$, we have that $f(x/c+1)=cf(x)=f(x+1/f(x))$, which, by using that $f$ is injective, means that $x/c+1=x+1/f(x)$ for all $x$.  Then we have that $f(x)=1/(ax+1)$ where $a=1/c-1$ is a postive constant. It is easy to substantiate that all functions in this form satisfy the given equation $(1)$.

QED.

Answer (score 2):

OK, posting this as an answer since it's the most I can figure out at the moment:

If we suppose that $f$ is continuous and furthermore that it has $1$ in its image, then it is constant (and hence $1$ everywhere).

Proof: Suppose $f(t)=1$.  Then applying the functional equation, we find that $f(x)=f(t+x)=f(x+t)=f(x)f(tf(x))$.  From this we conclude two things: Firstly, $t$ is a period of $f$.  Secondly, cancelling the occurences of $f(x)$ (since, after all, $f$ is never $0$), $f(tf(x))=1$, that is to say, $tf(x)$ also has this same property as $t$, and hence is also a period of $f$.

So if $f$ has any irrational numbers in its image, then it would have two periods with irrational ratio, and hence have arbitrarily small periods; by the continuity assumption, this means $f$ is constant.

But on the other hand, if $f$ has no irrational numbers in its image, then by continuity, this also means $f$ is constant.

(Note that one can also get arbitrarily small periods without using continuity if one assumes that $f(x)<1$ for some $x$; but if you don't assume continuity, I don't know how to show $f$ is constant.)