# To find all functions $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x)f(yf(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

$f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$

and for all $x,y >0$ we have:

$f(x+y) = f(x)f(yf(x))$

Because it is very similar to $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$

it seems good to define $g:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$

$f(x) = e^{g(x)}$

Comment: The only one I see is $f(x)=1$.

Comment: if $f$ is not injective then there is one number $r$ such that $f(r)=1$ then $f(r+y) = f(y)$ for all $y$ so we can analyze $f$ in $(0,r)$

Comment: Do you know, dear friend, that  interval $(0,r)$ can behave like all $\mathbb R$? I thought of a periodic $f$ with period $1$ but it was a lost illusion.

Comment: Yes there are bijections between intervals. It is just interesting: if $f$ is not injective than it must be periodic or constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall prove that all solutions are: the constant function $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+bx}$ with an arbitrary $b>0$.

**Claim 1.** $f$ is bounded from above by $1$.

**Proof.** For the sake of contradiction suppose that $f(t)>1$ for some $t>0$. Note that $\dfrac{t}{f(t)-1}>0$ so we may substitute $x=t$ and $y=\dfrac{t}{f(t)-1}$ in the equation. Observe that $x+y=yf(x)$ so $f(x+y)$ and $f(yf(x))$ cancel out leading to $f(t)=1$. This is a contradiction as $t$ was assumed to satisfy $f(t)>1$. $\square$

**Claim 2.** $f$ is nonincreasing.

**Proof.** By Claim 1. we have $f(yf(x))\le 1$ for all $x,y>0$ and therefore
$$f(x+y) = f(x)f(yf(x)) \le f(x) \cdot 1 = f(x),$$
which shows that $f$ is nonincreasing. $\square$

Now suppose that there exists $t>0$ such that $f(t)=1$. Substitute $x=t$. We obtain $f(t+y)=f(t)f(yf(t))=f(y)$ for all $y>0$. So $f$ is periodic and also nonincreasing by Claim 2. Hence $f$ must be constant and since $f(t)=1$ it must be $f(x)=1$ for all $x>0$. This function clearly works.

From now on assume that $f(x)<1$ for all $x>0$.

**Claim 3.** $f$ is strictly decreasing. In particular, $f$ is injective.

**Proof.** For all $x,y>0$ we have 
$$f(x+y) = f(x) f(yf(x)) < f(x) \cdot 1 = f(x). \square$$

Substituting $y:=\dfrac{y}{f(x)}$ we get 
$$f\left(x+\frac{y}{f(x)}\right)=f(x)f(y).$$
Changing the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the above equation we get 
$$f\left(y+\frac{x}{f(y)}\right)=f(y)f(x)$$
which implies that for all $x,y>0$ we have 
$$f\left(x+\frac{y}{f(x)}\right)=f\left(y+\frac{x}{f(y)}\right)$$
and, by injectivity, 
$$x+\frac{y}{f(x)}=y+\frac{x}{f(y)}.$$
Fixing $y$ and calculating $f(x)$ from this we see that $f(x)$ is of the form $\dfrac{1}{a+bx}$ for some constants $a,b$. It remains to substitute $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{a+bx}$ into the original equation and calculate the values of $a,b$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a+b(x+y)} &= \frac{1}{a+bx}\cdot \frac{1}{a+by\frac{1}{a+bx}} \\
a+bx+by &= (a+bx)(a+by\frac{1}{a+bx}) \\
a+bx+by &= a^2+abx+by \\
(a-a^2) + (b-ab) x &= 0
\end{align*}

It follows that $a-a^2=0$ and $b-ab=0$. This means $a=1$ and $b>0$ arbitrary or $a=b=0$. First case leads to $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+bx}$ and these functions clearly work. Second case leads to division by $0$ and is therefore impossible.