# Solve the functional equation $f(y)f(xf(y))=f(x+y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions f defined over the **positive reals**.

$f(y)f(xf(y))=f(x+y)$

I proved that $0<f(x)<1$;

If a positive number $t$ such that $f(t)>1$ exists,

By setting $x$ as $\frac{t}{f(t)-1}$, and $y$ as $t$,

We get $f(t)=1$, which is a contradiction.

So for all $x$, $f(x) \le 1$.

$f(x) \not = 1$ can easily be proved, so

for all $x$,

$0 < f(x) < 1$.

Also got;

By setting $y$ to $x$ and vice versa, $f(x)f(yf(x))=f(x+y)=f(y)f(xf(y))$.

Please help.

Comment: How did you prove it was injective, that $f \equiv c$ and that $0 < f < 1$? You need to add these things to your post. Because naively looking at the equation, it would seem that setting $x = 0$ implies $f(0) = 1$, contradicting your statement about $0 < f < 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add a bit more.

Comment: Also, f is defined over the positive reals, so you can't set x to 0.

Comment: $f(x+a)=f(x+b)$ for distinct $a$ and $b$ does not necessarily mean $f\equiv c$. Take $f(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $a=1$, $b=2$. where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_function). It may still be true that $f$ must be constant or injective, but your proof of that is not sufficient.

Comment: Oh yes, i see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To find all functions $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x)f(yf(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660662/to-find-all-functions-f-0-infty-rightarrow-0-infty-such-that-fxy)

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer WhatsUp's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the function $f$ maps positive real numbers to positive real numbers.

---

**Step 1**: We show that $f(y) \leq 1$ for any $y$.

(This has been worked out in the question. I give proof for completeness.)

Suppose there is $y$ such that $f(y) > 1$. Then putting $x = \frac y {f(y) - 1}$ in the original equation gives $f(y) = 1$, contradiction.

As a corollary, the function $f$ is non-increasing: for any $y < z$, putting $x = z - y$ in the original equation gives $f(y) \geq f(z)$.

**Step 2**: If there exists $a$ such that $f(a) = 1$, then $f$ is constantly equal to $1$.

Putting $y = a$ in the original equation gives $f(x + a) = f(x)$. Thus by induction, we get $f(ka) = 1$ for any $k \in \Bbb Z_{> 0}$.

For any $x$, we may choose sufficiently large $k$ such that $x < ka$. Since $f$ is non-increasing, this leads to $f(x) \geq 1$ and hence $f(x) = 1$.

**Step 3:** The remaining case.

From now on, we suppose that $f(x) < 1$ for all $x$. The same argument as above shows that $f$ is strictly decreasing, and in particular is injective.

We replace $x, y$ in the original equation with $x + y - xf(y), xf(y)$ (note that these are positive real numbers). This gives:
$$f(xf(y))f((x + y - xf(y))f(xf(y))) = f(x + y).$$ Together with the original equation, we get $f((x + y - xf(y))f(xf(y))) = f(y)$. By injectivity of $f$, this implies $$(x + y - xf(y))f(xf(y)) = y.$$
We now set $x = \frac z{f(y)}$ in the above equation, which becomes
$$\left(\frac z{f(y)} + y - z\right)f(z) = y.$$ After algebraic transformation, we get
$$\frac 1 y \left(\frac 1{f(y)} - 1\right) = \frac 1 z \left(\frac 1{f(z)} - 1\right).$$ This being valid for all $y, z$, we see that $\frac 1 y \left(\frac 1{f(y)} - 1\right)$ is a constant, independent of the value of $y$.

If we denote this constant by $c$, then we get $f(y) = \frac 1{cy + 1}$. It is easy to verify that this is a possible solution to the original equation.

---

Thus either $f(y) = 1$ for all $y$, or there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(y) = \frac 1{cy + 1}$ for all $y$.

Comment: Sorry, but $f$ is not yet proved to be a injective function. Please check the comments of the problem. Thanks for writing down this long solution.

Comment: @HJS Please read the whole answer, from very beginning. In Step 3 I treat the remaining case where $f(x)$ is never equal to $1$ and have shown that $f$ must be injective in that case.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thanks for the long answer and the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry to question a correct solution, but is there some reason(motivation) why you set $x,y$ to $x+y-f(x), xf(y)$ at STEP 3?

Comment: This more or less comes from experience. The aim is to try to get something that is "closely related" to the original equation. Setting these parameters would allow us to get two identical terms in the equations.

Comment: Oh, so it's basically intuition with a bit of logic.